# USB Soundcard resets when no sound is played

Tags: sound, shutdown, soundcard

my USB sound interface (M-Audio Fast Track Ultra 8R) works fine but when I stop playing sound it seems to "shut down" after about 5 seconds (green lights pop up which happens on windows only if you start the device - and I get a huge sound pop which is quite annoying). Once I start a sound after it has "shut down", the same problem reoccurs (like it's "booting up").
It seems almost as if the driver tells the device to shut down due to no sound played.

Is there a way to fix this?

Here's some output:

```
$ for d in /sys/bus/usb/devices/[0-9]* ; do if [[ -e $d/product ]] ; then echo -e "`basename $d`\t`cat $d/power/control`\t`cat $d/speed`\t`cat $d/product`" ; fi ; done
1-1.4.1.1   on  480 Ultra Fast Media Reader
1-1.4.1.2   on  12  Razer DeathAdder
1-1.4.1.3   auto    480 USB2.0 Hub
1-1.4.1.3.1 on  1.5 G110 G-keys
1-1.4.1.3.3 on  1.5 Gaming Keyboard G110
1-1.4.3 on  12  Hua Xing
2-1.5   on  480 Fast Track Ultra 8R

$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.5/power/control
on
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.5/power/level
on
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.5/power/autosuspend_delay_ms 
2000
$ cat /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.5/power/autosuspend
2
$ cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend 
2
$ cat /sys/module/usbcore/parameters/autosuspend
2
```

cat /lib/udev/rules.d/42-usb-hid-pm.rules

```
# do not edit this file, it will be overwritten on update
#
# Enable autosuspend for qemu emulated usb hid devices

# Note that there are buggy qemu versions which advertise remote
# wakeup support but don't actually implement it correctly.  This
# is the reason why we need a match for the serial number here.
# The serial number "42" is used to tag the implementations where
# remote wakeup is working.
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{product}=="QEMU USB Mouse", ATTR{serial}=="42", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{product}=="QEMU USB Tablet", ATTR{serial}=="42", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{product}=="QEMU USB Keyboard", ATTR{serial}=="42", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"

# Catch-all for Avocent HID devices. Keyed off interface in order to only
# trigger on HID class devices.
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="0624", ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="03", TEST=="../power/control", ATTR{../power/control}="auto"

# Dell DRAC 4
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="413c", ATTR{idProduct}=="2500", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"

# Dell DRAC 5
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="413c", ATTR{idProduct}=="0000", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"

# IBM remote access
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04b3", ATTR{idProduct}=="4001", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04b3", ATTR{idProduct}=="4002", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04b3", ATTR{idProduct}=="4012", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"

# Raritan Computer, Inc KVM.
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="14dd", ATTR{idProduct}=="0002", TEST=="power/control", ATTR{power/control}="auto"

# USB HID devices that are internal to the machine should also be safe to autosuspend

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{removable}=="removable", GOTO="usb_hid_pm_end"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb", ATTRS{removable}=="unknown", GOTO="usb_hid_pm_end"

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{bInterfaceClass}=="03", ATTRS{removable}=="fixed", TEST=="../power/control", ATTR{../power/control}="auto"

LABEL="usb_hid_pm_end"
```

Note that laptop-mode is not installed, it's a desktop pc with a fresh ubuntu 13.10 install.

Comment: could this have to do something with usb autosuspend? if yes, how do I disable it?

Answer (score 0):

How are you?

Do you try with ACPITOOL?

use acpitool -w to determine the available wake-up level for the USB controller.

Running this on my system shows S1 for the USB controllers:

$ acpitool -w
   Device   S-state   Status   Sysfs node

---

1. LID      S3    *enabled
2. PBTN     S4    *enabled
3. PCI0     S3    *disabled  no-bus:pci0000:00
4. USB0     S1    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
5. USB1     S1    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.1
6. USB2     S1    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.2
7. USB3     S1    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.7
8. MODM     S3    *disabled
9. PCIE     S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1e.0

To disable it after you have booted, you can try

echo 1 > /sys/bus/usb/devices/your-USB-device/power/autosuspend

echo "on" > /sys/bus/usb/devices/your-USB-device/power/level

Give it a try... anything else, let me know. Be care.

Comment: Can you post result of this command? "sudo acpitool -w", thanks

Comment: neither of the two commands help.

Comment: sudo acpitool -w: http://pastebin.com/WLkzAAk2